# Rails 3.1 vs 3.0 AJAX syntax difference. Equivalent statement in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Working through "Agile Web Development with Rails" edition 4 and hit the section on beginning AJAX. (Chapter 11 iteration F2). In the example code, the book using Rails 3.0 recommends creating:

app/views/line_items/create.js.rjs with the file only containing:

```
page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart))
```

What would an equivalent implementation for rails 3.1 using jQuery be?

app/views/line_items/create.js.erb?

```
$('#cart').html(?something magical here?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better do:

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

Comment: I see... still fumbling my way around in Rails in general too. So the .erb extension essential works as a pre-processor that after executing any embedded ruby will render the remainder like a regular js file?

Comment: Do you have any references to this? EG: Why I'd better do $().html() rather than using page.replace_html()?

Comment: What does escape_javascript do? I understand jQuery's .html(), but can't figure it out. why $('#cart').html("<%= render(@cart)%>") doesn't work?