# Rails 3.1: How to access `page' (JavaScriptGenerator) in a ajax js response

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to replace some HTML on the current page of a rails app.

I have the button with the `:remote => true` and have the `format.js` in the respond_to block of my line_items_controller#create method:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

I have created a file `app/views/line_items/create.js.erb` with the following line it it:

```
<%= page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart)) %>
```

However when I click the button and see what is returned from the server in chromes version of firebug I get this:

```
NameError in Line_items#create

Showing /home/hamstar/Development/railsbook/depot/app/views/line_items/create.js.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `page' for #<#<Class:0x007f08583aea50>:0x007f085839acd0>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart)) %>
```

So that page object is the JavaScriptGenerator right?  How can I access that object in the `create.js.erb` file?  Do I need to initialize it in the `#create` method?

Every resource I've looked at seems to show that it would just work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171963/rails-3-1-vs-3-0-ajax-syntax-difference-equivalent-statement-in-jquery - maybe we can't access the page object anymore in rails 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RJS is gone: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/49-rails-3-1-and-the-jquery-effect

So I guess the page JavascriptGenerator object was a protoype generator belonging to RJS.

See also: [Rails 3.1 vs 3.0 AJAX syntax difference. Equivalent statement in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171963/rails-3-1-vs-3-0-ajax-syntax-difference-equivalent-statement-in-jquery)

Have to use this now:

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```